# jQuery Validation - Run on previously hidden elements

Tags: jquery, html, validation

I have 2 forms in lightboxes (Using Magnific Popup). By default, jQuery validation is adding validation to the first form when displayed but it won't work for any of the others as they are set to `display: none;` by the Lightbox plugin.

I need it so that the validation is removed on the open form and will run on the second form if their visibility is switched. I have it set up in JS Fiddle to see how it's currently working.

http://jsfiddle.net/sLc3n5s1/

Comment: It's working fine for me... I'm opening both pop ups, and using "asd" as email, both forms are returning errors in that input field.
You want those "error messages" to be "reset" from each form at switching?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer. If from within one of the lightboxes you click the link at the bottom to switch to the other lightbox (Sign Up or Sign In) the validation will not run.

Comment: The fields are also not resetting when the lightboxes are closed.

Comment: Please include the code in your question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of things you need to do.

1. Give both the forms ids so they are easily accessible.
2. Separate validation code for each form and validate should be called in
   document ready instead of open event of popup plugin.
3. Store return value of validate method in global variable.
4. Call resetForm method of validation plugin as per requirements.

Final Code: ONLY JS

```
jq = jQuery;
jq(document).ready(function() {
    runValidation();
    // Lightboxes
    jq('.mpf-open').magnificPopup({
        type: 'inline',
        mainClass: 'mfp-with-fade',
        removalDelay: 300,
        closeBtnInside: true,
        closeOnBgClick: false,
        callbacks: {
            open: function() {
                if(document.objValidSignIn) {
                    document.objValidSignIn.resetForm();
                }
                if(document.objValidSignUp) {
                    document.objValidSignUp.resetForm();
                }
            },
            close: function() {
                if(document.objValidSignIn) {
                    document.objValidSignIn.resetForm();
                }
                if(document.objValidSignUp) {
                    document.objValidSignUp.resetForm();
                }
            },
            change: function() {
                if(document.objValidSignIn) {
                    document.objValidSignIn.resetForm();
                }
                if(document.objValidSignUp) {
                    document.objValidSignUp.resetForm();
                }
            }
        }
    });

    jq('form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});

jq.validator.setDefaults({ 
    ignore: [],
    // any other default options and/or rules
});

document.objValidSignIn = false, document.objValidSignUp = false;

// Validation
function runValidation() {
    document.objValidSignIn = jq('#SignInForm').validate({
        onsubmit: true,
        focusInvalid: false,
        rules: {
            // Sign In
            signin_email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            signin_password: {
                required: true
            },
            signin_terms: {
                required: true
            },
            signin_guidelines: {
                required: true
            }       
        },  
        highlight: function(element) {
            jq(element).closest('.required').removeClass('valid').addClass('error');
        },
        success: function(element) {
            jq(element).text('OK!').addClass('valid').closest('.required').removeClass('error').addClass('valid');
        }
    });
    document.objValidSignUp = jq('#SignUpForm').validate({
        onsubmit: true,
        focusInvalid: false,
        rules: {
            // Sign Up
            signup_name: {
                required: true,
            },
            signup_screenname: {
                required: true,
            },          
            signup_email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            signup_passwordonce: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 8
            },
            signup_passwordtwice: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 8,   
                  equalTo: '#passwordonce'
            },
            signup_terms: {
                required: true
            },
            signup_guidelines: {
                required: true
            }           
        },  
        highlight: function(element) {
            jq(element).closest('.required').removeClass('valid').addClass('error');
        },
        success: function(element) {
            jq(element).text('OK!').addClass('valid').closest('.required').removeClass('error').addClass('valid');
        }

    });

}
```

DEMO: NOT working with jsfiddle could be because of global variables. It is working perfectly in the jsbin environment.

http://jsbin.com/qoqivanisupe/1/edit